# Page Refresh or Manual URL Change issue in Angular 6 App in IIS

Tags: angular, routes

I had created an Angular 6 app and deployed in local IIS.If i refresh at any page or trying to change the routing URL manually application goes to the starting page. My application works fines in local but the issue occurs only in IIS so if i host in any other server also the same issue occurs.Am using URL Rewrite in IIS.

web.config

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<configuration>
  <system.webServer>
    <rewrite>
        <rules>
            <rule name="angularjs routes" stopProcessing="true">
                <match url=".*" />
                <conditions logicalGrouping="MatchAll">
                    <add input="{REQUEST_FILENAME}" matchType="IsFile" negate="true" />
                    <add input="{REQUEST_FILENAME}" matchType="IsDirectory" negate="true" />
                    <add input="{REQUEST_URI}" pattern="^/$" negate="true"/>
                </conditions>
                <action type="Rewrite" url="/MyApp" />
            </rule>
        </rules>
    </rewrite>
  </system.webServer>
</configuration>
```

In Index.html

```
 <base href="/MyApp/">
```

In app.module.ts

```
under providers:
{ provide: APP_BASE_HREF, useValue: '/MyApp' },
```

How to fix this issue?Thank you in Advance..